# Как изменить значение словаря swift

Tags: ios, swift

Есть система -  mainArray,массив содержащий несколько dictionatry1. dictionary1  содержат несколько - array. array содежат несколько dictionary. Как обратиться к элементам dictionary и изменить значение по ключу?
Как поменять значение в обычном словаре, я знаю, а как изменить в данной системе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обращайтесь как и к обычным элементам, просто наворотили систему. Разбирайте пошагово и обращайтесь к нужному:

1. Берете нужный элемента массива (в данном случае у вас `dictionary`)
2. В `dictionary` по ключу к нужному массиву
3. В нужном массиве к `dictionary`
4. И докапываетесь до нужного элемента в `dictionary`

Кодом:

`arrOuter[arrOuterIndex][dictOuterKey]![arrInnerIndex][dictInnerKey]`

Comment: если не трудно, можете пример привести? если честно, то не сильно догнал код, который Вы написали (арроутер))

Comment: @Yurjke, я обобщенно написал. ArrOuter - Ваш внешний массив, mainArray. В нем элементы, обращаетесь к dictionary по индексу arrOuterIndex, ну и т.д. по цепочке.

Comment: arrOuter[arrOuterIndex] уже стоит ставить ?, не гарантирован элемент, дальше надо получений элемент кастить в Dictionary и проверять на успех

Comment: @DmitryA. это просто для примера. Конечно не стоит использовать force unwrap, а необходимо использовать optional chaining, как Вы указали и затем проверку на nil/ optional binding if let/guard let по вкусу